# Dictionaries with matrix values in matlab

Tags: matlab

I tried to create a dictionary {integer:matrix} in matlab using container.Map but it is not possible. Is there a way to create such a dictionary?

Comment: I think it is possible with `containers.Map`. Check out http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html and go to
**Create a Map with Nonscalar Values**

Comment: Can you post the code from you attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say i have 3 matrices `a`,`b` and `c`. I can achieve the task by doing this

```
keySet = [5,10,15];
valueSet = {a,b,c};
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet);
```

Hope that helps !